# My mesh is not moving like the motion tracked video

Tags: tracking

With lots of help of you I ended up with [this movie](https://youtu.be/eHmd4WTSRCY). Something has gone wrong because my mesh is moving .... Any ideas what has gone wrong ?

[image]

Comment: @cegaton Sorry, I will do better again next time. If you feel I don't improve, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solve error is too high:

[image]

You should aim for a tracking error of 0.3 (a third of a pixel)

Revisit your tracking marks and make sure they are not sliding. If they are re-track or try a different tracking mode.

Read: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332)

Comment: hmmm ... Blender Guru said that any value between 1 and 3 is good and values below 1 are very good. So it had to be below 1 ? Because I stopped  since I had a value close to 1